# Spring Security accountNonExpired credentialsNonExpired implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am implementing Spring Security in my project referring [from](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/)

In class CustomUserDetailsService.java

The boolean variable "enabled", "accountNonExpired", "credentialsNonExpired" are explicitly set to true and returned with the User object.

```
        boolean enabled = true;  
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;  
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;  
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;  

        return new User(  
                domainUser.getLogin(),   
                domainUser.getPassword(),   
                enabled,   
                accountNonExpired,   
                credentialsNonExpired,   
                accountNonLocked,  
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())  
        );
```

For a user account these variable will always be true in this way. Suppose the admin wants to disable the user account how will he set boolean enabled to false. I don't understand this functionality. Can anyone help?

Do I have to add these fields in User class and create db fields too for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you'd have to add those fields to your User class and store them in the database. You could then use `accountNonLocked` to lock users out who exceeded unsuccessful login attempt count.